# Unable to resolve module redux on React Native project

Tags: react-native, redux

Since the new release of react-native (0.26.0) I'm getting this error when I init a new project. I get the same error when I npm install other modules like redux and then those dependencies aren't found at run time. Anyone else having an issue like this or have any ideas?

```
> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install /Users/danseethaler/Developer/Test/node_modules/utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild

2016-05-21 21:33:02.797 xcodebuild[6298:183020] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID ACA8656B-FEA8-4B6D-8E4A-93F4C95C362C for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/XcodeMultiEdit.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2016-05-21 21:33:02.935 xcodebuild[6298:183020] Build settings from command line:
2016-05-21 21:33:02.935 xcodebuild[6298:183020]     ENABLE_BITCODE = NO
2016-05-21 21:33:02.935 xcodebuild[6298:183020]     SWIFT_DISABLE_REQUIRED_ARCLITE = YES
2016-05-21 21:33:02.935 xcodebuild[6298:183020]     SWIFT_LINK_OBJC_RUNTIME = YES
2016-05-21 21:33:02.936 xcodebuild[6298:183020]     TOOLCHAINS = com.apple.dt.toolchain.XcodeDefault
2016-05-21 21:33:02.936 xcodebuild[6298:183020]     XCODE_DEFAULT_TOOLCHAIN_OVERRIDE = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node
ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Release/validation.node] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:204:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 15.4.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/danseethaler/Developer/Test/node_modules/utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v5.10.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 Exit status 1
Test@0.0.1 /Users/danseethaler/Developer/Test
└── react@15.0.2
```

Comment: I got the unable to resolve module react-redux when I ran the application. My react-native version is 0.26.1.

Answer (score 10):

try this .solve mine,

```
 npm i redux --save
```

Answer (score 2):

Little late to the party too, however I think you might be missing

`'redux': ^{compatable react-redux version}`
in your `package.json`

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. Click "Reset content and settings..." in the simulator's drop down menu and confirm
2. Close the simulator after it reloads
3. Close the terminal window running watchman
4. Run the following commands within terminal inside of your project's directory. If you don't have yarn installed, run these commands instead.

   ```
    watchman watch-del-all
    rm -rf ./node_modules
    npm cache clean
    rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*
    npm install
    npm cache clean
    npm install uuid
   ```
5. Rebuild the project inside of Xcode and be sure to make any suggested modifications prior to running the app.

Answer (score 1):

A little late with this answer, but in my case this required me to restart my iOS emulator. I followed the instructions show in my log file (from `react-native log-ios`)

```
    This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
        To resolve try the following:
          1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
          2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
          3. Reset packager cache: `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
```

Hope that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In the project I inherited, the Git repo contained two sub-directories, `./packages/mobile/` and `./packages/state-manager/` --and there was a top-level (small) `package.json` file that installed dependencies for both upon invocation of the `yarn setup` command. Before learning of this, I had been trying to run `yarn` down in the `./packages/mobile` folder and getting the feared red-screen and error. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your source files are not located in a folder by the name **redux**.
Once I renamed the folder to something else, the error disappeared.