# UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module `./node_modules/react-native/packager/src/components` React Native

Tags: ios, npm, react-native, npm-install, react-native-ios

I'm building an app using React Native and I got this error.

I tried to clear cache and install packages again, but still having issues.

This is the error message from terminal.

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 2): UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module
>   `./node_modules/react-native/packager/src/components` from
>   `/Users/andy/Downloads/testapp/index.ios.js`: Directory
>   /Users/andy/Downloads/testapp/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/components
>   doesn't exist

And below is the screenshot of iOS simulator.[image]

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Does this path "/Users/andy/Downloads/testapp/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/components" exists in your system?

Comment: I can't find it, how can I add it?

Comment: You don't have to add it if it doesn't exist. Try changing the relative path instead. Are you trying to import something in your index.ios.js?

Comment: import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native'
import { Root } from 'app/components'

AppRegistry.registerComponent('autospa', () => Root)

Comment: This is the content of index.ios.js.

Comment: [check my solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45251228/3694459)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you by any chance using babel-plugin-module-resolver as one of your dependencies? Do you happen to have a directory called src with a subdirectory called components? If so I think you might have run into a similar issue that I run into recently, that the app should really look into src/components for the components while it is looking into the wrong path (under node_modules).

We were able to temporarily solve the problem by running npm start -- --reset-cache, then refreshing the simulator 2 to 3 times afterwards, although we're now looking into getting rid of bable-plugin-module-resolver altogether.

Here is a related issue:
https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver/issues/138

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is something wrong with how you are importing your "Root" file. Check the current hierarchy and check your relative path to import Root file.